# Automatically sync USB data to documents?

Tags: usb, sync

Is their a way to sync USB data onto my documents folder with only the newest files being copied.

I use my USB pen drive to transform data from college and home so this would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of options out there. I use Microsoft's (free) [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en) to backup stuff to and from my laptop. You can either schedule it to run at certain times via Windows Scheduler (look at the help menu to learn how) or have a script run it whenever you connect your pen drive.

At any rate, define a folder pair between your pen drive and the destination folder and set your backup to add new files and change old files only, to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I like Robocopy, but there are programs like [AllwaySync](http://www.allwaysync.com/) (free for personal use).

With Robocopy you could have two batch files, one to copy from the flash drive to your hard drive, the other batch file to copy things back.

If you want the destination folder to be identical to the source folder you can use the `/mir` for mirror.  If you only want things a few days or so old, you can set time limits so if things are newer than *x* days old, then it will be copied.